Do we need two projects in Blazor Web App in .Net 8 with auto interactivity rendering mode?
Blazor web app with auto render creates template with 2 projects.So the question is:

Can we have single project? can we add @rendermode InteractiveAuto on all pages even if we don't need client side interaction?
What is best interactivity rendering mode practice for apps with basic CRUD and no chat like features.

Created Blazor Web App template. Trying to figure out the best rendering mode to decide Application structure.

Your question is not specific to one subject. Stackoverflow is not the best place to ask for tutorials and resources. It is really hard to provide an answer to your question. Please follow the rules for asking questions on SO: Be specific, provide your current code/attempts ask your questions.
